# Can I show PCI compliant Logo

Tags: pci-dss

I have just now got 20 of my e-commerce websites scanned and certified by Comodo. 
I will be submitting them to my banks as well to prove that I am PCI compliant.

But is there any regulation on who can show any pci logo and is there any choice of pci logo.

Comment: PCI is not regulated, you'd have to ask them whether it is ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) ASV scans, while part of PCI compliance, do not make you PCI compliant.  You also need a valid SAQ or passing audit by an approved QSA, depending upon your volume.

2) I'm not aware of any PCI-approved logo or seal.  In general, PCI compliance is a matter for direct relationships, e.g. you need to give your processor a copy of your scans and your SAQ or your AOC and ROC.  You can look up your processor in the [Service Provider Listing](http://www.visa.com/splisting/).  Seals don't mean anything because anyone can put them up.

The acronyms:

- ASV - Approved Scanning Vendor
- QSA - Qualified Security Assessor
- SAQ - Self Assessment Questionnaire
- AOC - Attestation of Compliance, what your QSA gives you.
- ROC - Report on Compliance, what your QSA gives you.

Comment: Sometimes your ASV scan provider will have a seal or something that they offer that will link to a site showing the status of your last scan. Use of the PCI logos is restricted to those who actually have an affiliation with them like the ASV or QSA companies.

Answer (score -1):

1. I am not sure that there is separate logo or any seal for the placing the PCI logo on your website.
2. If you're using [Comodo PCI Compliance](https://www.hackerguardian.com/hackerguardian/learn/pci-scan-compliancy.html) then you can increase upper hand by consoling clients that you are approved to acknowledge charge cards by setting a high perceivability trust indicator on your site
3. Simply placing a mouse cursor over the card logos produces a bright green border around the browser window, giving website visitors instant verification that a merchant can legitimately accept card payments.